# Java Out of memory occured when memory is still available in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, caching, memory, out-of-memory

As I know, In the linux system, cached memory for increasing performance of Disk IO operation and it'll be released whenever some processes request to allocate memory.

But recently, I got OOM (out of memory) that caused shutdown my java application while the cached memory is still available (~ 250MB) and my existing java application java heap is Xms:128MB and Xmx:256MB. I captured the **free -m** command and kernel error

[image: free -m command]

[image: kernel error]

Do you have any ideas in this case. Any help will be nice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post the complete error message and java version?

It should contain some description of the exhausted memory pool (i.e. heap, permgen, etc) useful to determine the cause of the exception.
The memory available at OS level is obnly one of the potential causes (not very frequent).
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html for further details.

Most of the times OOM are not due to memory available at OS level, and can be resolved simply avoiding to add a bunch of objects to collections.

OutOfMemory are usually due to exhaustion of space within the JVM (mostly the heap).
i.e. with Xmx you limited the heap to 256m: if you keep references for objects using more than 256m you will run out of heap space and hence get an OOM. Something similar for permgen with classes or classloading leaks.

The heap is the amount of memory allocated to the JVM to host objects, and should not be confused with OS memory.
The JVM starts with a certain heap size (Xms), then asks additional memory to the OS, until it reaches the maximum limit (Xmx).
In the meantime, the garbage collector cleans up memory (with multiple approaches, based on runtime conditions, JVM version, config and so on).
So you should revisit your logic and avoid retaining too much object into memory, or increase the Xmx.
Something similar happens for classes/code and other memory pools (varying with jvm implementations).

If you are experiencing a memory leak you could analyze allocated memory using http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks001.html

Comment: agree. I can add "give java version" because of changes in memory / GC architecture

Comment: @JacekCz sure, added